# Что быстрее: роутер & роутер + адаптер

Tags: роутер

Добрый день!

1. Используется домашний интернет
2. Есть WiFi роутер NetGear WNR3500L (802.11n)
3. есть адаптер NetGear WNCE2001 (802.11n)

Есть вариант установить роутер при входе в квартиру, чтобы не тянуть кабель до рабочего места, а к системному блоку подключить адаптер.

Вопрос: насколько сильно такое подключение будет медленне, чем вариант тянуть кабель к рабочему месту и подключать роутер напрямую к системному блоку?

Comment: Во много раз медленнее. Во первых кабель быстрее WiFi (хотя конечно от вашего тарифа зависит). Во вторых эфир в крупных городах сейчас сильно забит и WiFi работают не очень. в третьих через стену и дверь квартиры сигнал обычно плохо проходит. Что бы не тянуть кабель можно еще использовать PowerLine (интернет через розетку 220)

Comment: Присоединяюсь к вышесказанному, и добавлю, что к процессору, вы мало чего подключить сможете :)

Comment: Формально, 802.11n может обеспечить канал до 150 Мбит/с. На практике все равно все будет определяться не скоростью передачи а пропускной способностью внешнего канала. (Если только на выходе не оптика с супер крутым тарифом.)

Comment: Слишком много внешних факторов. Задержка наверняка будет повыше, а скорость, да, будет скорее ограничена провайдером, чем роутером.

Comment: простите, но если у вас на входе 1Мбт то вайфай не будет гнать больше.
получается , провод , далее все проводом, и вайфай в итоге
к вышеперечисленому соглашусь, даже телеки на вайфае :)